# Medical Sciences SE Statistics

Tags: discussion, statistics

On the sidebar of the Medical Sciences SE statistics for questions vs. answers are displayed:

[image]

5436 divided by 6378 is not 68%.

If answered equals accepted answers, this may be misleading because it assumes community involvement (accepting the question) for a question to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer to my question so far is, as suggested by Carey Gregory on Meta:

[Area 51 %Answered: can we have decimals?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254161/area-51-answered-can-we-have-decimals/289684#289684)

Apparently not the most accessible formula: 
Answered = AcceptedNotClosed + PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed + Closed
%Answered = 100 * Answered / Asked

So it does include to some extent a measurement of community involvement in the answering process.

Comment: We just increased our answer percentage to 69%.

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that the definitions of these stats are as follows:

- *questions* = The total number of questions posted.
- *answers* = The total number of answers posted.
- *answered* = The total number of questions with at least one answer.

Remember, there can be (and often are) multiple answers on a single question. So to clarify, let's do a simple example. Let's suppose this is day 1 of the site and nothing has been posted. It would go like this:

1. **Starting values:** *questions* = 0, *answers* = 0, *answered* = 0%.
2. **The first question is posted:** *questions* = 1, *answers* = 0, *answered* = 0%.
3. **An answer is posted:** *questions* = 1, *answers* = 1, *answered* = 100%.
4. **Another answer is posted:** *questions* = 1, *answers* = 2, *answered* = 100%.
5. **The OP accepts one of the answers:** [No change]
6. **A second question is posted:** *questions* = 2, *answers* = 2, *answered* = 50%.

I believe these stats work the same on all SE sites, so if you doubt my answer I would recommend asking on meta.stackexchange.com (search first; it's probably been asked).

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this means it would be a questions:answers ratio, but then again 5436:6378 is not 0.68 (same as above). I agree, those stats will probably be the same on the whole network. I'll have a look on the meta, thanks.

Comment: @Thomas "% answered" is **NOT** a ratio of questions to answers.

Comment: @Thomas As Bryan said, it's definitely not a questions/answers ratio. How could it be when questions often have multiple answers? A single answer to a question increments the _answered_ counter, but additional answers do not. See the definitions above.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a significant detail in the definition:

Questions = The total number of questions posted and **not deleted**. It's important as a fair amount of questions here are getting deleted by the self-deletion script (e.g. [>50% of questions got closed the Medical Sciences Stack Exchange in 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346725/178179)).